# It it possible to Trace who deleted records in SQL Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are Many SQL Servers hosted on different different Servers.

All Servers are working based on "SQL Server Authentication". So the Same Login is used by many people in the Organization.

How to trace who deleted some of the records in particular table?

Do we need any additional coding like Triggers are required or its a in-build feature of SQL server to provide those details?

Please help me.

Thank You.

Comment: I would recommend a log table if you need to do something like this. You can archive all changes and deletions.

Comment: This is worth a try [LINK](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4269/how-to-find-out-who-deleted-some-data-sql-server)

Comment: It is also worth noting that if you are the DBA, then you really should look into the security aspect here. If lots of people use the same SQL Server login and that login has rights to `DELETE` that's a problem. One day someone is going to destroy something by accident and you may be the one to get in trouble for it when it could have otherwise been avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the deletion has already occurred and you had nothing in place to track / log this, then the chances are going to be very low - they are not zero, but not far above it.

If you use the transaction log to identify the exact deletion and the session id of the deletion, which we already know is the shared user login - and you have got successful login security auditing enabled you would in theory be able to trace it back to the IP address that made the deletion.
However - that is a pretty slim chance - I would suspect that the login is from the actual application software and you would of needed that to be running directly on the users machine, e.g not a 3-tier / web based server of any flavor, but a good old thick client app making direct connections.
That gets you an IP and a time, but not a who was logged in on that machine at that time, if its shared in any form, then you are having to get login records on the machine etc.